# Django on Dreamhost - testing/sand box environment

Tags: django, passenger, wsgi, dreamhost

I've been using webfaction for all my django needs for the last couple of years but have had a high traffic site fall in my lap that dreamhost are probably better suited to handling.

To set up and experiment with a site with webfaction there are your `[user].webfactional.com` accounts. Which is sweet.

Equivalently Dreamhost also offers `[name].dreamhosters.com`

Yet this doesn't seem to work with my database and this doesn't seem to be playing nice with setting up django or `passenger_wsgi`.

So I'm wondering if I'm interpreting the documentation correctly to suggest that in order to make a site that depends on passenger it needs to be running from an active domain. The documentation is really implicit, I'm baffled.

Has anyone set up a testing/sand box environment for django using dreamhost, or know how to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've setup a Django site on Dreamhost on a dreamhosters subdomain before so I can tell you for sure it is possible.

I'm not sure what you mean by active domain but I know that you have to set something to the effect of "Allow Passenger for this domain" under "Manage Domains" > "Web Options". Your `passenger_wsgi.py` file should be placed in `~/[name].dreamhosters.com/` and needs to include all the necessary project/application paths (including the Django source) as well as set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable as described in the [Dreamhost wiki](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Django). As far as database connections there is nothing special that you have to do in the settings when using Passenger.

On a somewhat related note, I would have to question your statement

> ...have had a high traffic site fall in
>   my lap that dreamhost are probably
>   better suited to handling.

given that Webfaction is by far the top rated host for Django and Dreamhost the absolute worst according to [DjangoFriendly](http://djangofriendly.com/hosts/). It's possible that many of the reviews were written when Dreamhost was only supporting FastCGI and things might have improved when using Passenger but I still don't think it beats Webfaction's options of FastCGI, mod_python, and mod_wsgi (which is the recommended deployment setup according to the Django docs http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/howto/deployment/modwsgi/).

Comment: thank you! ... against probability got it going. It's an extremely simple django site but we want to experiment with VPS which sadly webfaction doesn't offer on a scale these guys need (though I do love webfaction). Dreamhost meets the criteria for this site well.